# Issue establishing connection with SAP

Tags: excel, vba, sap-gui

I am trying to establish connection using SAP GUI from Excel VBA and keep getting the same 424 error.

> Runtime Error 424 “Object Required”

I've tried multiple ways changing variables but nothing seems to be working for me :(

[image]

[image: screenshot]

```vb
If Not IsObject(Application) Then
   Set SapGuiAuto = GetObject("SAPGUI")
   Set Applicationa = SapGuiAuto.GetScriptingEngine
End If
If Not IsObject(Connection) Then
   Set Connection = Applicationa.Children(0)
End If
If Not IsObject(session) Then
   Set session = Connection.Children(0)
End If
If IsObject(WScript) Then
   WScript.ConnectObject session, "on"
   WScript.ConnectObject Application, "on"
End If
session.findById("wnd[0]").resizeWorkingPane 131, 25, False
session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlIMAGE_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").doubleClickNode "F00006"
```

Comment: Line number 7 "Set Connection = Applicationa.Children(0)"   right after this one. I just reuploaded the image, marked in yellow. Thank you!

Comment: Notice that you use `Application` previously. Should that be `Applicationa`?

Answer (score 2):

I guess the SAP GUI Scripting Engine is not activated on the client or server side, you can use this way to localize the problem:

```
On Error Resume Next ' note that you will need to check errors mannualy

'check SAPGUI is running
Dim guiSAP As Object: Set guiSAP = GetObject("SAPGUI")
    
If guiSAP Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("SAPGUI is not running!"), vbCritical, "SAP GUI"
    Exit Sub
End If

'check that scripting engine is activated
Dim appSAP As Object: Set appSAP = guiSAP.GetScriptingEngine

If appSAP Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("SAP GUI Engine is not activated!"), vbCritical, "SAP GUI Scripting"
    Exit Sub
End If

'check connection to SAP
Dim connectionSAP As Object: Set connectionSAP = appSAP.Children(0)

If connectionSAP Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("SAP connection lost!"), vbCritical, "SAP Connection"
    Exit Sub
End If

'check SAP session
Dim sessionSAP As Object: Set sessionSAP = connectionSAP.Children(0)

If sessionSAP Is Nothing Then
    MsgBox ("No Active SAP Session!"), vbCritical, "SAP Session"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Vasily, it helped me to identify the first problem. After running the following line " MsgBox ("SAPGUI is not running!"), vbCritical, "SAP GUI" i get a pop up window "SAP GUI is not running" . Right now i am looking to fix that, I have already enabled SAP GUI API in VBA preferences, but still nothing.

Comment: @StasPegov "SAP GUI is not running" means that GUI not initialized, so you need to be logged in to SAP before running the script.

Comment: i am logged in, but still get the same pop up. Well i will try to find a way to fix it. Thank you for helping me out!